# Proving that for every integer $n, n^3 + n$ is even via contraposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I know this is trivial with direct proofs, but how would one go about proving:

> For every integer n, n^3 + n is even

using contraposition? I'm a little rusty on how to properly use contrapositive proofs. I know that if given $P \Longrightarrow Q$, the contrapositive is $\neg Q\Longrightarrow \neg P$.

So to prove via contraposition, assume $\neg Q$ is true and if $\neg P$ logically follows, then we have shown $P \Longrightarrow Q$.

$Q$ or $\neg Q$ is trivial, however, what is $P$ in this case?

Edit:

This was just out of curiosity in trying to figure out ways to prove this indirectly.

Comment: You can rephrase it as "If $n$ is an integer, then $n^{3} + n$ is even", if that helps.

Comment: You can't really prove this via a contraposition in any meaningful way. I guess you could look at the proof as $n \in \mathbb{Z} \implies n^3 + n$ even, and therefore the contrapositive would be $n^3 + n$ odd $\implies n\not \in \mathbb{Z}$, but that sounds quite difficult on the face of it. Really the core issue is that there isn't a natural way to form an implication with this claim.

Comment: Was "*via contraposition*" a requirement of the problem, or your own idea of a way to try solve it?

Comment: I've already proved it directly but wanted to try doing so indirectly. But yeah, now that you guys mentioned it, "...then $n \not \in \mathbb{Z}$ seems... difficult.

Comment: @Zar That's useful context, and you should add it into the question. This problem is not well suited to solving by contraposition, because the premise is implicit into the problem itself. You could technically restate it as a contrapositive, as noted in a previous comment, but that would make it virtually indistinguishable from a reductio ad absurdum, at least not without splitting a lot of hairs.

Comment: If you don't find my answer as useful, you can send feedback to delete it .

Comment: @dxiv Do you think, using some logic symbols is part of this problem ?

Comment: @lonestudent I don't think logic symbols are a main issue here. The problem itself is ill-suited to a pure contrapositive proof, and a proof by contradiction is technically [not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774879/equivalence-of-contrapositive-and-contradiction-proofs-with-quantifiers) exactly the same thing.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you dxiv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Over-View :

I have given a way to generate the Contra-Positive , then I have suggested a way to Prove that.
That Proof is long & Cumbersome , hence I have suggested a variation with a slight alteration , which gives a Simple Proof By Contra-Positive.

---

Statement given is like this ( With $Z$ = Integral Numbers ) :
$P_1$ : $\forall n \in Z : Even(n^3+n)$

It has no Implication , hence Contra-Positive will not arise.

We have to make it with Implication to get a Contra-Positive. Doing that requires using a larger Universal Set ( Eg With $Q$ = Rational Numbers &  With $R$ = Real Numbers ) .

**These 2 will work :**
$P_2$ : $\forall n \in Q : Integer(n) \implies Even(n^3+n)$
$P_3$ : $\forall n \in R : Integer(n) \implies Even(n^3+n)$

**Then the Contra-Positives are :**
$P_4$ : $\forall n \in Q : \lnot Even(n^3+n) \implies \lnot Integer(n)$
$P_5$ : $\forall n \in R : \lnot Even(n^3+n) \implies \lnot Integer(n)$

---

**Proof By Contra-Positive :**

When $n^3+n$ is not Even , we have $n^3+n=2m+1$ which has the Unique Solution (real) given by Wolfram :

[image: CUBIC]

Problem now becomes showing that $N$ is not Integer , no matter what Integer $M$ is.
That can be done , though it require too much unnecessary work.

**Thus Proof By Contra-Positive is too Cumbersome here.

Direct Proof is much Easier !**

---

Now , it is your Curiosity to try this type of Proof , hence we can make it easier to go forward by considering this :
$P_6$ : $\forall n \in R : Integer(n) \implies Even(n^2+n)$

The Contra-Positive is :
$P_7$ : $\forall n \in R : \lnot Even(n^2+n) \implies \lnot Integer(n)$

When $n^2+n$ is not Even , we have $n^2+n=2m+1$ , which gives :

$n=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4(2m+1)}}{2}$

$n=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+8m+4}}{2}$

$n=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{8m+5}}{2}$

No matter what $m$ is , $8m+5$ is not a Square ( It is easy to check that $S^2 \equiv 1 \mod 8$ & $S^2 \not \equiv 5 \mod 8$ ) , hence $n$ is irrational , not Integer !

**We have the Proof By Contra-Positive here !

Direct Proof will work Easier too.**

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted your question as follows :

> Prove that, if $n$ is an integer, then $n^3+n$ is always even for all $n\in\mathbb Z$ , using the method of [Proof by contradiction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) .

Suppose that, there exist $n\in\mathbb Z$ , such that $n^3+n$ is an odd integer .

If $n^3+n$ is odd, then $n(n^2+1)$ is odd. This implies that, $n$ and $n^2+1$ can not be even integers . Thus, $n$ is odd . If $n$ is odd, then $n^2+1$ is an even integer .

A contradiction .

Answer (score 1):

If we rewrite your statement for integers modulo $2$, then it says: "for every element $n$ in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ we have $n+n^3=0$." But $n^3=n$ in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, so we have:

For every $n$ in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ we have $n+n=2n=0$.

This is clear, because $2=0$ in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. Now we can prove this also by contradiction. Suppose that $2n$ is nonzero. Then $n$ and $2$ are nonzero in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. This is a contradiction to $2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose contradiction i.e. there exists some integer $n$ for which $n^3+n$ is odd.
Thus for some integers $n$ and $k$, you must have
$n^3+n=2k+1$
$\implies n^3+n-2=2k-1$
$\implies (n^3-1)+(n-1)=2k-1$
$\implies (n-1)(n^2+n+2)=2k-1$
$\implies (n-1)[n(n+1)+2]=2k-1$
You can argue why $[n(n+1)+2]$ is always even for $n(n+1)$ being the product of consecutive integers, which makes LHS an even integer; but RHS is odd. Hence the result.